# Is it possible to launch a WinUI 3 C# Application without Xaml?

Tags: c#, .net-core, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I've been following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3) to try simplifying the `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` files from the standard VisualStudio Blank WinUI 3 template into a single `App.cs` file.

So far, I've got a version that compiles:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MyApp;

public class App : Application
{
    private Window _mainWindow;

    public App() {}

    protected override void OnLaunched( LaunchActivatedEventArgs args )
    {
        Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new XamlControlsResources() );

        _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        _mainWindow.Activate();
    }

    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        App.Start(
            ( ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams callback ) =>
            {
                new App();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't end up actually launching the UI because the call `new XamlControlsResources()` throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with the message `Unspecified Error`.

Is there any way to bootstrap a WinUI3 / Windows App SDK / .NET app in C# code without the Xaml?

## Update

As you can see, I've accepted [Jeaninez - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11872808/jeaninez-msft)'s answer (below).

Here is what the final *working* **App.cs** file, which uses the type `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo.XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider` to satisfy the interface `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlMetadataProvider`, as in the [C++ project on GitHub](https://github.com/sotanakamura/winui3-without-xaml/blob/master/main.cpp) that Jean recommended.

*(Note that the call* `Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new XamlControlsResources() );` *must occur within the* `OnLaunched` *override. If you call it in the* `App` *constructor, it throws the* `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` *that I referred to above.)*

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo;
using System;

namespace MyApp;

public class App : Application, IXamlMetadataProvider
{
    private Window _mainWindow;
    private XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider provider;

    public App() { }

    [ STAThread ]
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Application.Start(
            ( ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams callback ) =>
            {
                new App();
            }
        );
    }

    public IXamlType GetXamlType( string fullName )
    {
        return provider.GetXamlType( fullName );
    }

    public IXamlType GetXamlType( Type type )
    {
        return provider.GetXamlType( type );
    }

    public XmlnsDefinition[] GetXmlnsDefinitions()
    {
        return provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched( LaunchActivatedEventArgs args )
    {
        XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider.Initialize();
        provider = new();

        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new XamlControlsResources() );

        _mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        _mainWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, what you need to do is implementing a `IXamlMetadataProvider interface`. This interface implements XAML type resolution and provides the mapping between types used in XAML markup and the corresponding classes implemented in an application or component.

For more details, I suggest you could refer to the c++ sample: [WinUI 3 in C++ Without XAML](https://github.com/sotanakamura/winui3-without-xaml)

Comment: Thanks very much! In addition to adding using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo.XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider` to satisfy the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlMetadataProvider` interface, I also had to move the call to `Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new XamlControlsResources()  )` to the `OnLaunched` method.